# linq how to GroupBy correctly

Tags: c#, linq

I have following class:

```
class AssembledDTO
{
    int pid,
    int blockId,
    List<string> references
}
```

I am trying to group by everything in following way:

```
AssembledParts.GroupBy(entry => new
                        {
                            entry.PID,
                            entry.BlockId
                        }).
                        Select( (key , val)=> new AssembledDTO
                            {
                                BlockId = key.Key.BlockId,
                                PID = key.Key.PID,
                                References = val.
                            })
```

In  `References` I want to get list of all `references` added together of each group that I grouped by.

How I can do so ?what I miss here ?

Comment: Have you tried `References = key.ToList()` ?

Comment: @I4V I dont see there ToList()

Comment: Please do not re-post! http://stackoverflow.com/q/16773147/861716 Edit your question in stead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectMany` should do the trick to flatten results.

```
AssembledParts.GroupBy(entry => new
                    {
                        entry.PID,
                        entry.BlockId
                    }).
                    Select(key => new AssembledDTO
                        {
                            BlockId = key.Key.BlockId,
                            PID = key.Key.PID,
                            References = key.SelectMany(v => v.references).ToList();
                        })
```

Comment: Downvoter - would you kindly give me some hints on what is wrong with this answer? I have not tested it, but seems to be what Night Walker is looking for. If I make mistake - I would like to know and to correct myself.