# what is wrong with my GroupBy Query

Tags: c#, linq

Hello all what is wrong with my GroupBy query ?

I have following class:

```
public class AssembledPartsDTO
{
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public McPosition Posiotion { get; set; }
    public string Partnumber { get; set; }
    public string ReelID { get; set; }
    public int BlockId { get; set; }
    public List<string> References { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to perform following query:

```
assembledPcb.AssembledParts.GroupBy(entry => new
                        {
                            entry.PID,
                            entry.Posiotion.Station,
                            entry.Posiotion.Slot,
                            entry.Posiotion.Subslot,
                            entry.Partnumber,
                            entry.ReelID,
                            entry.BlockId
                        }).
                        Select( (key , val )=> new AssembledPartsDTO
                            {
                                BlockId = key.Key.BlockId,
                                PID = key.Key.PID,
                                Partnumber = key.Key.Partnumber,
                                ReelID = key.Key.ReelID,
                                Posiotion = new McPosition(key.Key.Station, key.Key.Slot, key.Key.Subslot),
                                References = val <-- ????
                            })
```

But the `val`  that I have there is of type `int` and not the val of grouping that I can do there `val.SelectMany(v => v).ToList();` any idea what is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter of [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) is the index of the item in the sequence. So in this case it is the (zero based) number of the group. You just want to select the group, you don't need it's index:

```
var result = assembledPcb.AssembledParts.GroupBy(entry => new
{
    entry.PID,
    entry.Posiotion.Station,
    entry.Posiotion.Slot,
    entry.Posiotion.Subslot,
    entry.Partnumber,
    entry.ReelID,
    entry.BlockId
})
.Select(g => new AssembledPartsDTO
{
    BlockId = g.Key.BlockId,
    PID = g.Key.PID,
    Partnumber = g.Key.Partnumber,
    ReelID = g.Key.ReelID,
    Posiotion = new McPosition(g.Key.Station, g.Key.Slot, g.Key.Subslot),
    References = g.SelectMany(entry => entry.References)
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToList()
});
```

(assuming that you want a list of distinct references)

Side-Note: you have a typo at the property-name: `Posiotion`